# Prevent the debian installer from assuming that my RTC is using localtime

Tags: debian-installer, clock

I've just installed a debian system, and just like the last time 10 years ago, it has b0rked my machine by assuming that my real time/hardware clock was using localtime, despite me not having told it so. It apparently based its decision on the simple existence of a NTFS filesystem on a partition.

I had to edit the `/etc/adjtime` file by hand and change the `LOCAL` to `UTC`.

Is there some simple change that I can do to the ISO "net install" image to prevent it from doing that?

The installer from Debian 9.9.0 is switching directly to a graphical menu upon boot, so there's no command line where I may pass any options to it.

Don't tell me to use the "expert" mode; it may start asking me all kind of expert-level questions I may not have the answer to ;-)

Comment: How about using `timedatectl` after installation completed?

Answer (score 1):

You can preseed `clock-setup/utc` to [skip the auto-configuration](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/clock-setup/blob/master/finish-install.d/10clock-setup#L63) (which, as you say, considers the clock to be local time if it finds a Windows, or DOS, system). To do so, the simplest option in your case seems to be to add `clock-setup/utc=true` to the boot options. Assuming an EFI boot, you can do this in the ISO image by editing `boot/grub/grub.cfg` to add that setting to the `linux` line, something like

```
linux    /install.amd/vmlinuz vga=788 clock-setup/utc=true --- quiet
```

You’ll need to re-generate the ISO of course.

If you can manage to get the Grub menu before the installer starts, you can edit the kernel boot options there.

Any other preseed option will work too; see [the installation manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apb.html.en) for details.

(“Expert” mode would also allow you to change the setting.)

Comment: It turns out that pressing `Esc` at the boot menu will bring up a command line. I'll have to test if entering `install clock-setup/utc=true` has the expected effect.

Comment: also, the grub.cfg from the iso image can be edited *in place* by taking advantage of its lots of white space, without having to regenerate the iso image -- but I wonder if anybody else will want to do that besides me.